# Euler characteristic of a convex polyhedron

Tags: general-topology

In the Euler characteristic proof of a convex polyhedron, how can you show two cellular decompositions of two different polyhedron contain a common refinement?

Answer (score 1):

Let the polyhedra be $P_1,P_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. By translating them we may assume that the interior of each contains the origin. Let $S$ be a sphere centered on the origin whose interior contains each of $P_1,P_2$. For $i=1,2$, project the vertices and edges of $P_i$ from the origin out to $S$ to obtain a cell decomposition of $S$ denoted $\Sigma_i$. So, your question comes down to finding a cell decomposition of $S$ which is a common refinement of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$. Notice that each edge of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ is a circle on $S$ (not necessarily a great circle). It follows that the intersection of any $\Sigma_1$ edge and any $\Sigma_2$ edge is either a single point or an arc. From this it follows that the union of the 1-skeleta of $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ is the 1-skeleton of a cell decomposition $\Sigma$ which is a common refinement of $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$.

Comment: Thank you but How is each edge a circle? Looks like some kind of an arc. Is there a picture?

Comment: Also what is the definition of union of 1-skeleta?

Comment: The 1-skeleton of a cell decomposition is the union of $0$-cells and $1$-cells

Comment: And, actually, I take back my parenthetical remark: any segment inside a sphere, when centrally projected out to the sphere, yields a segment of a great circle. To see this, notice that the projection takes place in the 2-plane that contains the center and the segment.

Comment: I think that makes sense. A straight line segment inside a sphere projected on to a sphere makes a segment of a great circle. Intersection of segments gives a single point (NOT an arc). Correct? Still what is the union of 1-skeleton? How do you define it?

Comment: Literally the set theoretic union. The 1-skeleton of $\Sigma_1$ union the 1-skeleton of $\Sigma_2$.

Comment: Could you please define it explicitly?

Comment: The set of all points $x$ such that either $x$ is an element of the 1-skeleton of $\Sigma_1$ or $x$ is an element of the 1-skeleton of $\Sigma_2$.

Comment: why does not this trick work for non-convex polyhedra?

Comment: For a convex polyhedron $P$ containing the origin $O$ and contained inside a sphere $S$ centered on the origin, the central projection map from the boundary of $P$ out to $S$ is one-to-one. But if $P$ is not convex, the central projection need not be one-to-one.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @J.A: Take any nonconvex polyhedron $P$. Take two points $x,y \in P$ such that the segment $\overline{xy}$ is not contained in $P$. By translating $P$ we can assume $x=O$ is the origin. The segment $\overline{xy}=\overline{Oy}$ pierces the boundary of $P$ at (at least) two points $x',y'$. The central projection from $O$ to the boundary of $P$ projects both of the points $x',y'$ out along the ray $Oy$ until they hit the same point of the sphere, where that ray pierces the sphere.