# How do you show Euler characteristic of any convex polyhedron is $2$?

Tags: general-topology

In the Euler characteristic proof of a convex polyhedron, how do you show the cell decomposition of projection of two polyhedra 1) have a common refinement AND 2) that common refinement comes from addition of vertices or deletion of edges?

Comment: Closely related question by the same user: [Euler characteristic of a convex polyhedron](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/987306/euler-characteristic-of-a-convex-polyhedron)

Comment: First, I think, you meant boundary of a 3-dimensional compact polytope. Secondly, if you know about homotopy-invariance of Euler characteristic, the solutions is quite simple.

Comment: @studiosus I just need a simple proof:) what is homotopy invariance?